# What's the proper way to use jQuery in conjunction with 'use strict'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, use-strict

If I have something like the following

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

I get the warning

```
'$'is not defined
```

Comment: It's implied by your question title, but if you remove the "use strict" directive does the code work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
( function ( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        console.log( 'working!' )
    })
} ( jQuery ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jQuery to your site?

Trying the same code on tinker.io produces the error, but then add the jQuery lib and the error goes away.

CDN: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

add it by using this snippet

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```